# Video Lessons in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, education, online-resources

Does anybody have some link for good video lessons of a complete course in Complex Analysis?
Grateful.

Answer (score 8):

[MIT video lectures part 1](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-008-calculus-revisited-complex-variables-differential-equations-and-linear-algebra-fall-2011/part-i/)

There are 5 videos covering complex numbers, functions, conformal mappings, sequence and series, and integration.

The speaker is professor Herbert Gross

---

There is also the Kahn Academy's [basic complex analysis videos](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/imaginary_complex_precalc/complex_analysis/v/basic-complex-analysis)

---

I just found out that Bernd Schroder from Louisiana Tech has videos on Complex Analysis based off of Churchill and Brown's text.

[Introduction to Complex Analysis](http://www2.latech.edu/~schroder/comp_var_videos.htm)

Comment: I was hoping there is a relatively advanced lecture for complex analysis, which quickly covers materials in Robert Ash's Complex Variables, leaving time for topics beyond, e.g. topics in special functions and complex differential equations. I had such courses before but unfortunately I have no videos of them. I really would like to review these materials through a good video lecture series.

Comment: @TroyWoo take a look at the new link I posted. I am not sure if it is want you want but it covers a wide variety of topics.

Comment: This time much better :-). I will try it and compare it with my previous education.

Comment: @TroyWoo, Steven Miller's [Complex analysis course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL71JUoXcec_mmLm9psjMKo1FYBXS9WHb7&pbjreload=10) is pretty advanced, I loved his presentation, and enthusiasm.

Comment: Also, Prof Bernd S Schroder's lectures are amazing, they go from bottom to top (unlike Miller's lectures, which are fast moving and cover some applications as well). Schroder's webpage link is now dead, but one can find them [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160613065752/http://www2.latech.edu/~schroder/comp_var_videos.htm). Schroder is awesome teacher, I fell in love with his style as soon as I read his Mathematical Analysis text, and hence I spent much time searching for his complex analysis lectures.

Answer (score 3):

The India Institute of Technology has a series which I have found helpful. There are a lot of videos and the presentation is straightforward lecture.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QaN9Qlr7CIU&index=40&list=PLbMVogVj5nJS_i8vfVWJG16mPcoEKMuWT) is one. I believe there are about 40 total.

The accent is pleasant to my ear and makes these easier to sit through than they might otherwise be. I have only listened to a few so far because my connection is slow but for a student with a robust inet they would be great.

Answer (score 2):

There is a course on Coursera, called Analysis of a Complex Kind.

Here is the link:

https://www.coursera.org/course/complexanalysis

Answer (score 1):

[Complex Analysis (2015)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBY4G2o7DhF0TSossUvJ-CTKSLfOhQgb6)

by James Cook of Liberty University following Gamelin's Complex Analysis. His [webpage](http://www.supermath.info/Complex.html) also has a supplementary guide to Gamelin.

Answer (score 1):

The [complex analysis video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8yHsr3EFj537_iYA5QrvwhvMlpkJ1yGN) from professor Richard E. BORCHERDS's [youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIyDqfi_cbkp-RU20aBF-MQ) is great.