# Good video lectures on complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, online-resources

I would like to find a complete series of video lectures on complex analysis, preferably with the following conditions:

- The videos are in English and clearly recorded. (Using English as a second language, I find it hard to understand spoken English when the sound is not clear.)
- The videos constitute a complete course and they are intended for students in mathematics who already have some familiarity with "serious" mathematics, i.e., they are decently fast paced and rigorous, and the content is deep enough.

There are already several posts here about video lectures on complex analysis, but I don't know which one will be approapriate for me. For the background, I have studied mathematical analysis from the first seven chapters of Rudin's text. I hope the videos will be at the level of, say, Conway's book (or anything like that). I will clarify any vague points in the above description, just leave a comment. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Steve Miller's lectures from his undergraduate complex analysis class at Williams College are available for free on youtube, along with several other video series from classes he's given.

Comment: Please leave a comment before downvoting, so that I'll get to know what kind of questions not to ask here.

Comment: This is not an answer, but if you are familiar with Rudin's books, then why not studying Chapter 10 of his Real and Complex Analysis? It explains all the basic theory succintly but deeply at the same time. P.S.: I am not the downvoter. (I agree that downvoters should comment to explain their reasons)

Comment: @Nitin Thanks, I'll take a look at that. :)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Actually, the reason why I'm looking for video lectures is that I'm busy with school (I'm still a high school student, so...). I won't have time to seriously read texts this year, but I would really love to learn complex analysis. Therefore I'm considering spending some sporadic time (say, on weekends) on watching video lectures... I hope that'll work out for me.

Comment: There is this older post: [Video Lessons in Complex Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1033670). (I found it simply by looking at the questions [tagged online-resources+complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources+complex-analysis).) Although I am not sure to which extent the answers there satisfy your requirements.

Comment: @MartinSleziak In fact I've checked out all the older posts that I can find here, but there are many of them posted so I don't know which one will suit me well. I think I've clearly described the kind of course that I'm looking for, so if anything is vague just point it out and I'll add more details. I'm currently watching Steven Miller's lectures as suggested by Nitin, and they seem to be nice. :-)

Comment: [Imaginary Numbers are Real](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiaHhY2iBX9g6KIvZ_703G3KJXapKkNaF)